# Tengo que invertir un vector en c

Tags: c, pseudocódigo

Buenas! Estoy empezando a programar en pseudocodigo similar a C y me dieron un ejercicio que realmente me esta costando mucho...
la consigna es:
Invertir un arreglo de 30 números enteros ingresados por teclado.(no puedo usar metodos de ordenamiento como burbujero, por ejemplo)
Ya cree el vector y la carga, pero la parte de invertirlos es la que no puedo sacar...
Alguien me puede dar una ayudita? Gracias!

```
int v[30]; // creo el vector
int aux; // creo un auxiliar
int cont=0; // creo el contador

while(cont < 30) { //cargo las 30 posiciones del vector
scanf("%d", &aux)
v[cont] = aux
cont++
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La alternativa mas sencilla creo yo es que hagas una operación swap. Para ello requieres de un bucle y una variable temporal

```
int temp;
```

La operación consiste en ir elemento por elemento a través del arreglo (hasta la mitad) y hacer un intercambio entre el elemento i-ésimo y el elemento TAMAÑO - i, usando una variable temporal para no perder el valor al hacer dicho intercambio.

El programa se verá así:

```
int v[30]; // creo el vector
int aux; // creo un auxiliar
int temp; //variable temporal
int cont=0; // creo el contador

//ENTRADA DE DATOS
while(cont < 30) { //cargo las 30 posiciones del vector
    scanf("%d", &aux)
    v[cont] = aux
    cont++
}

//SWAP
cont = 0;
while(cont < 30/2)
{
    temp = v[cont];
    v[cont] = v[30 - 1 - cont];
    v[30 - 1 - cont] = temp;
    cont++;
}
```

La variable temporal es necesaria porque si hiciéramos lo siguiente:

```
   v[cont] = v[30 - 1 - cont];
   v[30 - 1 - cont] = v[cont];
```

Perderíamos por siempre el valor de `v[cont]`

Comment: La respuesta está acomodada a tu estilo de programación y al tamaño del arreglo. Por supuesto que hay varias optimizaciones de estilo que se pueden hacer en el programa pero no quiero confundirte.

Comment: Hola Marcos, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero hay algo que no entiendo, el contador del swap no deberia ir aumentando en cada iteracion? Gracias!

Comment: Cierto! No agregué el contador. Eso iba a provocar un ciclo infinito. También arreglé el índice del `v[30 - 1 - cont] = temp;` El íncide irá incrementando (0, 1, 2...) para `v[cont]` y decrementando (29, 28, 27...) para `v[30 - 1 - cont]` Gracias Pil

Comment: Ahi me cierra mas! gracias a vos! Saludoss

Comment: Puedes evitar recurrir a variables temporales: `v[cont] = v[cont] ^ v[29-cont]; v[29-cont] = v[cont] ^ v[29-cont]; v[cont] = v[29-cont] ^ v[cont];`

Answer (score 0):

```
int numero[100], numeroInvertido[100];

int i = 100 - 1, j = 0;
while (i >= 0)
{
    numeroInvertido[j] = numero[i];

    j++;
    i--;
}
```

Comment: Las respuestas de solo código se consideran de baja calidad, por favor lee [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Hola Josua, esta respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Por favor, edítala para añadir más detalles: ¿qué hace este código? ¿dónde iría? ¿cómo resuelve el problema de la pregunta? Lee [answer] y visita el [tour] para más información.